# counting car using opencv+python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

hello every on i have some problem .sir i want to count  the vehicles, going step by step

1. read video
2. apply background subtraction
3. use contours concept for rectangle
4. also working on the  optical tracking algorithm
   after that they counting the car in each frame, i want to count a car in whole video in one time.

**this my code**

```
import cv2
backsub = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\Python27\code\car.avi")
best_id=0
i = 0
if capture:
  while True:

    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret:
        fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, None, 0.01)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
        except: hierarchy = []
        for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
            (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if w > 20 and h > 20:
                # figure out id
                best_id+=1
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, str(best_id), (x,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        print(best_id)        
        cv2.imshow("Track", frame)
        cv2.imshow("background sub", fgmask)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == ord('q'):
            break
```

Comment: please specify your problem better. if the fps is high enough, you can "label" those rectangles, assuming their center should not move too much at the next frame. You can dynamically define a threshold for this, using old velocity information. Also, a new label should happen near to boundaries -assuming video from still camera.

Comment: sir tracking is done bt after that how to count ......plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a line o the image, and everytime the centroid of the bounding box crosses that line, you could increment the count by 1.

Comment: hello sir i have done counting phase now i am working on classification on vehicle any idea ????

Comment: You could try to check the size of the bounding box when the vehicle crosses the line. Since the line is at a fixed distance, a larger vehicle should have a larger bounding box than a small vehicle.

Comment: If you are just working on one video the above suggested idea might work if you hard code values of the sizes of the bounding box, or the contour. However, for different videos, based on the angle, height from which the video was recorded, the above suggested method will fail.

Comment: You can provide your solution as answer here.

Comment: Hi @projecking I am working in something similar, I have to count vehicles and Im blocked. Now I can track the vehicles with optical Flow but I don't know how to count that vehicles, could you share your code please? or lgive me some advice. thank you!